# how to hide url details in default player in android

Tags: android

I call the default audio player using intent. Its playing correctly, but want to hide details of playing URL is display in top of the play.its my coding

```
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), mimeType);
startActivity(mediaIntent);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved with with such an implicit intent like that. This is because you have no control over the UI that is being used to play the content. In order to solve your problem, You must play the file using a specific class available in the framework.